TypeError: Failed to fetch at fetchRetry
One of my project is using next (version 12.2.4) and react (version 18.2.0). There is Webpack configuration in the next.config.js file and I think this is the main reason of the below error (triggered by /node_modules/next/dist/client/next-dev.js):
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at fetchRetry (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js:204:12)
    at getData (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js:231:16)
    at fetchNextData (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js:318:38)
    at _callee$ (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js:1337:56)
    at tryCatch (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:274:22)
    at prototype.<computed> [as next] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@swc/helpers/lib/_async_to_generator.js:23:28)
    at _next (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@swc/helpers/lib/_async_to_generator.js:12:17)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@swc/helpers/lib/_async_to_generator.js:17:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@swc/helpers/lib/_async_to_generator.js:9:16)
    at Router._getData (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js:1725:24)
    at _callee$ (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/router.js:1319:46)
    at tryCatch (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:274:22)
    at prototype.<computed> [as next] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@swc/helpers/lib/_async_to_generator.js:23:28)
    at _next (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@swc/helpers/lib/_async_to_generator.js:12:17)

next.config.js file:
const withImages = require('next-images');
const withFonts = require('next-fonts');

module.exports = withImages(
  withFonts({
    webpack(config, options) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader'
        }
      });

      config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false, crypto: false };

      return config;
    }
  })
);

The error is happening only sometimes and I do not know how to replicate it in 100%.
